# C# Programmatically Unminimize form

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I take a form that is currently minimized and restore it to its previous state.  I can't find any way to determine if its previous `WindowState` was `Normal` or `Maximized`; but I know the information has to be stored somewhere because windows doesn't have a problem doing it with apps on the taskbar.

Comment: I'm not going to waste anyone else's time trying to get this re-opened; but the alleged duplicate doesn't answer my question because it's answer will restore to normal (open but non-maximized) always, including if pre-minimization it was in the maximized state.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no managed API for this.  The way to do it is to PInvoke [GetWindowPlacement](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowplacement) and check for `WPF_RESTORETOMAXIMIZED`.

For details, see this [Microsoft How To](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110620) (which is demonstrating the technique in VB).

In C#, this would be:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);


private struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
{
    public int length;
    public int flags;
    public int showCmd;
    public System.Drawing.Point ptMinPosition;
    public System.Drawing.Point ptMaxPosition;
    public System.Drawing.Rectangle rcNormalPosition;
}

public void RestoreFromMinimzied(Form form)
{
   const int WPF_RESTORETOMAXIMIZED = 0x2;
   WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
   placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(placement);
   GetWindowPlacement(form.Handle, ref placement);

   if ((placement.flags & WPF_RESTORETOMAXIMIZED) == WPF_RESTORETOMAXIMIZED)
       form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
   else
       form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Comment: @Dan: Thanks - I fixed the errors - (I was typing on the fly, and copying from pinvoke.net, which had the ref/out issue wrong...)

Comment: @Dan: Sounds like this worked for you, though, at least ;)

Answer (score 10):

```
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

You also have:

```
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Ah, I misunderstood the question:

[Restore WindowState from Minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354445/restore-windowstate-from-minimized) should be what you're looking for. It says you can mimic the taskbar behavior like this:

```
SendMessage(form.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0);
```

Comment: That doesn't answer his question - he's asking whether to go to Normal or Maximized if the form is currently minimized...

Comment: I updated my answer. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution - very simple to implement.

Answer (score 3):

You can track the window state changes through the Resize event.  Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        prevState = currState = this.WindowState;
    }
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
        if (currState != this.WindowState) {
            prevState = currState;
            currState = this.WindowState;
        }
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
    private FormWindowState prevState, currState;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store the previous state whenever there's a change (maximize/minimize), you'll have to hook into the `SizeChanged` event, according to [this post on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9f3d1702-d165-4f84-9ffe-7c82cfd64c50/).  You can get the `WindowState` there and store it.

Comment: There's a better option than storing this yourself.  It's already tracked by the Windows API.