# Bring window to the front

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore WindowState from Minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354445/restore-windowstate-from-minimized)

I have window which is normally hidden in the tray bar.

Then I want to show it if it was hidden, and bring to the front.

If it's already opened, I want to just bring it to front.

And if it's minimized to task bar, then I want to expand it and bring to front.

Now I have this in my show method:

```
this.Show();
this.Activate();
this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
this.TopMost = true;
this.Focus();
```

But if it's minimized it will not expand.

How to fix this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is minimized, you will have to restore the window using the [WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx) property.

```
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; // To maximize
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; // To restore
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized`

For full details of the FormWindowState enum, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formwindowstate.aspx)

Comment: I would probably go with `FormWindowState.Normal` over `Maximized`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;    

this.Show();
this.Activate();
this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
this.TopMost = true;
this.Focus();
```